# GSM modem code through serial port

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, gsm

I have been trying to interface GSM modem with serial port (`RS232`). I access the serial port as `/dev/ttyS0` (`COM1`).

I am unable to send the AT commands to the device using C. I use Linux OS.

Comment: Please provide more information. The code you have tried, the module you are using (SIM300 or any other), the commands you are trying to give, the exact problem that you are facing, have you checked the hardware, LED diagnostic information etc.

Comment: Also, this question shall get better response on electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: You will need to correctly set the serial port parameters to correspond to your device. Serial port looks simple, however there is many options and they need to match, baudrate is one of them. `stty` is the command which can help you. You can start with `man stty` command.

Comment: What does [ModemManager](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ModemManager/) say?

Comment: The device is completely working fine. The AT commands work well in minicom as well as hyperterminal. I just don't know how to communicate with the serial port using C in linux. I know the values to set the serial port but to set those parameters, i cannot communicate.
@AbhishekBansal: elecronics.stackexchange.com has only gsm interfacing with microcontrollers. But i am using normal PC's serial port.

Comment: Is this SO question helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430023/writing-at-commands-embedded-linux

Comment: @ S List I tried that program too.. but still i do not get any reaction from the modem!The Baud rate and other parameters are set fine!